# Visual Studio PowerShell Out-File to .txt filenames not in order

Tags: winforms, powershell, visual-studio-2019

when i create an `Out-File` i open the `.txt` file the filenames are not in order please see code i am using and see the `Out-File`

i am using this to add the Number at the beginning.

```
$button20_Click={


$originalFiles = Get-ChildItem $textbox3.Text -Filter *.pdf
$x = 1

ForEach ($originalFile in $originalFiles) {
    Rename-Item -Path $originalFile.FullName -NewName (($originalFile.Directory.FullName) + "\" + $x + $originalFile.Name.substring(8))
    $x++

}
}
```

[image]

```
  $button6_Click = {

    $listBox2.items.clear()  
    $CreateRun = get-childitem $textbox3.text *.pdf 

    $outTXT = $textbox8.Text
    "`n",$textbox12.text ,"`n", $CreateRun.Name| Out-File $outTXT\$($comboBox1.SelectedItem + "-" + $comboBox2.SelectedItem + "-"+ $dateTimePicker1.Text)".txt"

     $showFile = GCI $textbox3.Text -Filter *.pdf
     Foreach($show in $showFile){
     $listbox2.Items.Add($show.BaseName)
       }
   }
```

Comment: The order is correct (for text), if you preceed the single digit numbers with a zero you will get the order you are looking for. You could also split on the first '.' convert to a number and sort on that.

Comment: @DavidMartin thank you for your comment, i have updated my question with the code i am using to add the numbers, i have tried making `$x=01` but that didn't do anything

Comment: @DavidMartin any chance of an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prefix file names with a (textual) sortable index number, you best use leading zeros for numbers, so `1.filename` becomes `001.filename` it the total number of files in the folder has that many files.

Something like this should do that:

```
$originalFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $textbox3.Text -Filter *.pdf -File
# calculate the number of digits needed to prefix with leading zeros
$numDigits  = $originalFiles.Count.ToString().Length
$startIndex = 1
$originalFiles | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ("{0:D$numDigits}.{1}" -f $startIndex++, $_.Name)
}
```

Original

```
D:\TEST
    test-INV67459-TW15 10DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 11DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 12DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 13DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 14DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 3DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 4DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 5DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 6DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 7DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 8DG.pdf
    test-INV67459-TW15 9DG.pdf
```

Becomes

```
D:\TEST
    01.test-INV67459-TW15 10DG.pdf
    02.test-INV67459-TW15 11DG.pdf
    03.test-INV67459-TW15 12DG.pdf
    04.test-INV67459-TW15 13DG.pdf
    05.test-INV67459-TW15 14DG.pdf
    06.test-INV67459-TW15 3DG.pdf
    07.test-INV67459-TW15 4DG.pdf
    08.test-INV67459-TW15 5DG.pdf
    09.test-INV67459-TW15 6DG.pdf
    10.test-INV67459-TW15 7DG.pdf
    11.test-INV67459-TW15 8DG.pdf
    12.test-INV67459-TW15 9DG.pdf
```